# How to get a json string using rest api for windows phone?

Tags: json, api, windows-phone-7

My Json is of the following format.

```
{
  "code" : o,
  "message" : "success",
  "book_list":
[
{"name": "C","price":180},
{"name": "C++","price":180},
{"name": "C#","price":180},
]   
}
```

I am a brand new beginner to Windows phone app development!!
How shall i get list of books from the url and store it in a dictionary kind of thing??(i.e as a key value pair) for windows phone 7??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this JSON framework for .NET](http://json.codeplex.com/):

```
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [DataContract]
    public class BookShop
    {

        [DataMember(Name = "code")]
        public int Code { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "book_list")]
        public List<Book> Result { get; set; }
    }


    [DataContract]
    public class Book
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "price")]
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }


 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{      
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string json = "{\"code\": 0,\"message\": \"success\",\"book_list\": [{\"name\": \"C\",\"price\": 180}, {\"name\": \"C++\",\"price\": 180 }, {\"name\": \"C#\",\"price\": 180}]}";

        var myObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BookShop>(json);

        foreach (var item in myObjects.Result)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("{0} has price {1}", item.Name, item.Price);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm currently working on it, but before that i just have a doubt///in the json string you have used there are many '\"' but i'm afraid that there are no such things in my string!! will it make a difference?? or it will work perfect??

Comment: It will work perfect http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k4fw5.aspx you can use also  string json = @"{""code"": 0,""message"": ""success"",""book_list"": [{""name"": ""C"",""price"": 180}, {""name"": ""C++"",""price"": 180 }, {""name"": ""C#"",""price"": 180}]}";

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I just have another doubt, suppose if the book is free then the price node will not be there(output will be {\"name\":\"C++\"}), in such case will it work properly??

Comment: yeah, you will have object Book with properties: Name = "C++" and Price = 0 (default value for C# Int)